# Query revisions where properties were modified and select a flag if property was modified

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-envers

I have the following class

```
public class Product
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual double Price { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
}
```

The audit table looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE Product_AUD (
    Id integer not null,
    REV integer not null,
    Price float,
    Price_MOD bit,
    Description varchar(255),
    Description_MOD bit,
    REVTYPE tinyint not null,
    primary key (id, REV)
);
```

My query looks like this

```
var revisionEntityInfos =
    Session.Auditer().CreateQuery()
           .ForHistoryOf<Product, DefaultRevisionEntity>()
           .Add(AuditEntity.Id().Eq(ProductId))
           .Add(AuditEntity.Or(AuditEntity.Property("Description").HasChanged(),
                               AuditEntity.Property("Price").HasChanged()))
           .Results();
```

So far this works and returns an `IEnumerable<Product, DefaultRevisionEntity>`.
I get all revisions where either the property `Description`, the property `Price` or both have changed. The information of `RevisionId` and `RevisionDate` is included.

But I also want to see which properties have changed for each revision, since I want to display this to the user. So basically I want to have the `HasChanged` flag in the result. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's currently not supported.

Feel free to add a [JIRA ticket](https://nhibernate.jira.com/projects/NHE) about this.